# Calling a method makes Error

Tags: objective-c, methods

I have one method with two arguments. one of them is an `Object` . when I want to call them it gives me this Error:

**reciver type "myView" for instance message does not declare a method with selector "findCp::"**

here is the code for my method that i made it less

```
-(double)findCp:(double)temp obj:(Component *)Obj{
    return temp;
}
```

here `Component` is a `NSObject` class that Obj is one of its Objects.
and I call my method in this way:

```
convertedTemp = [[self findCp:tempreture :Degree]doubleValue];
```

in actual code it makes some changes on temperature and give it back.
also in myView.h I put

```
-(double)findCp:(double)temp obj:(Component *)Obj;
```

why I get this error? am I calling my method wrong? am I wrong with definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you just call the method in a wrong way. Its signature is `findCp:obj:` instead of `findCp::`.
Your actual call should be:

```
convertedTemp = [self findCp:tempreture obj:Degree]; // You're returning a double already
```

PS. Also note that ivar names in Objc usually are named with a starting lowercase letter, while Class names with an uppercase one (by convention).

Comment: you were right. I should remove the `doubleValue` part and also put the name `obj` before the object. thank you